# How can I extract the Dnbr value in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, image

I'm trying to export the Dnbr value of each pixel, but i don't know how to do.
This is my code:

```
//SENTINEL2
var poligono = ee.FeatureCollection('users/florianaspatola/grassano');
print(poligono)

//pre-processing
// Function to mask clouds from the pixel quality band of Sentinel-2 SR data.
function maskS2sr(image) {
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // All flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // All flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  // Return the masked image, scaled to TOA reflectance, without the QA bands.
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

//Sentinel2
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterDate('2019-07-01', '2019-08-31')
  .filterBounds(table)
  .map(maskS2sr);
print(S2);
Map.addLayer(S2, imageVisParam4, 's2');
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table, {}, 'grassano');

//area_test
var pre_fire = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20190811T095039_20190811T095702_T33TWE');
print(pre_fire);
var visParams = {
  bands: ['B12', 'B8', 'B3'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
Map.addLayer(pre_fire.clip(table), imageVisParam4, '20190811_prefire');

//fire_21_08_2019
var fire_day = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20190821T095039_20190821T095437_T33TWE');
print(fire_day);
var visParams = {
  bands: ['B12', 'B8', 'B3'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
Map.addLayer(fire_day.clip(table), imageVisParam4, '20190821_fire');

//post_fire
var post_fire = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20190828T094039_20190828T094520_T33TWE');
print(post_fire);
var visParams = {
  bands: ['B12', 'B8', 'B3'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
Map.addLayer(post_fire.clip(table), imageVisParam4, '20190828_postfire');

//nbr_pre fire
var nbr_prefire = pre_fire.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B12']);
print(nbr_prefire);

//nbr_post fire
var nbr_postfire = post_fire.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B12']);
print(nbr_postfire);

//DNBR
var DNBR = nbr_prefire.subtract(nbr_postfire);
print(DNBR);
var dnbrclip = DNBR.clip(table);
print(dnbrclip);
Map.addLayer(DNBR.clip(table), {}, 'DNBR_s2');
```

Comment: You have to formulate this question a bit clearer. What do you mean by export the Dnbr value of each pixel? Where do you want to export it, and in what format do you want it exported? Also, please include a link to a running script where all used assets are shared.

Comment: Please make your asset `users/florianaspatola/grassano` available to everyone, otherwise people cannot run your script properly. Do you want each pixel value to be exported to csv matrix table?

Comment: I make my asset avaible to everyone. Yes i want each pixel value in csv matrix table.